# Perl capture variables in multiple binding operators

Tags: regex, perl, capture-group

Is there a way to use capture groups in more than binding expression and capture all the groups?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

countDays(1,"2015-3-21","2016-3-24");

sub countDays {
    die "Check formatting"
        unless ($_[0] =~ m/([1-7])/ &&
                $_[1] =~ m/^(\d{4})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})$/ &&
                $_[2] =~ m/^(\d{4})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})$/);

            # testing
            print "$1\n$2\n$3\n$4\n$5\n$6\n$6\n";

}
```

This only captures the last three groups: `$1`, `$2`, and `$3`.

Edit for expected output as Avinash Raj suggested:

```
1
2015
3
21
2016
3
24
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, every successful match resets all capture variables. But you can do this:

```
sub countDays {
    my @match1 = $_[0] =~ m/([1-7])/
        and
    my @match2 = $_[1] =~ m/^(\d{4})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})$/
        and
    my @match3 = $_[2] =~ m/^(\d{4})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})$/
        or die "Check formatting";

    print "@match1\n@match2\n@match3\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

countDays(1,"2015-3-21","2016-3-24");

sub countDays {
    my $countDays = join ',', @_;

    die "Check formatting"
        unless $countDays =~
            m/([1-7]),(\d{4})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2}),(\d{4})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})/;

    # testing
    print "$1\n$2\n$3\n$4\n$5\n$6\n$7\n";
}
```